# Nuxt 3 wrong (old) route in setup script

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I would like to use the route and its parameters in the setup script of a component in Nuxt 3. I run into a problem when navigating by nuxt-link where the route in the setup script of the component being routed to, is the one from the component triggering the routing.

Given the following reproduction, I would expect the full path in the test component to be `/test` and not `/`, whether the component is routed to from the browser or from a nuxt-link. In this example however, the route is only correct when routed to from the browser or via page reload.

## Reproduction

`npx nuxi init test`

`cd test`

`npm i`

/app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

/pages/index.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>index</h1>
    <nuxt-link to="/test">to test</nuxt-link>
</template>
```

/pages/test.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>Path: {{ fullPath }}</p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const fullPath = useRoute().fullPath;
console.log(fullPath);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt's built-in `useRoute` requires the use of `<NuxtPage>` which is a wrapper for `<router-view>` and should in fact replace `<router-view>`

**app.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

[NuxtPage documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page)

The rest of your code should work at this point.

For whatever reason if you do prefer the use of `<router-view>` over `<NuxtPage>` you can still make it work by importing vue-router's `useRoute` into your component.

**test.vue**

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const fullPath = useRoute().fullPath;
console.log(fullPath);
```

Comment: Smooth brain moment, thank you.